# How much work do widely-used templates make for the linker?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

Suppose I use `shared_ptr<MyAwesomeClass>` in 100 different cpp files. Will the compiler create a `MyAwesomeClass` specialization of `shared_ptr` in each and every one of the corresponding objs and then force the linker to sift through them all, select one winner, and remove all the losers?

If so, can this effect come to dominate link time, or will other operations take so much longer that it doesn't really matter?

I am trying to figure out why one of my projects takes 100+ seconds to link and another one of similar size gets done much faster. So far the only systematic difference I've identified is that the slow one makes heavy, widespread use of some of the newer standard library templates like `shared_ptr` and `function`.

The compiler/linker in question are Micrsoft's 2012 versions.

Comment: Groovy. I hate being a nit ;)

Comment: You'll have a large number of COMDAT sections, all with the same code.  The linker picks just one of them, throws away the rest.  Templates are not exactly cheap.  Whether that truly explains the slow link is not obvious.  Maybe you can get some insight from the /VERBOSE option.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious and I hate making little errors that set the teeth of the better-informed grinding, so I appreciate being set straight.

Comment: @HansPassant have tried /VERBOSE, but it didn't tell me much. Hard to say whether that's its fault or mine.

Comment: If visual c++ is your only target, you might benefit from using its precompiled header feature. Defining nontrivial constants in header files used to slow down the linker a lot but that was 10 years ago, not sure it applies still.

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan We actually do have a pretty large stdafx that includes many of the standard library headers, and I'm half-considering a followup question asking whether that makes link time better or worse.

Comment: If you actually use the stuff then it's likely ok. I would reccomend against aading all known header files "just in case"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is platform dependent, but if it is indeed the cause you can address it via [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by56e477.aspx) in VS 2013. Hopefully it will work also for 2012. Note that it's a part of the C++11 standard as noted by Captain Obvlious, so it's just a question of whether or not it was supported in VS 2012.

Comment: explicit template instantiation is not limited to Visual Studio nor is it an extension specific to any compiler, it's part of the C++ core language.

Comment: Maybe if you added the link for the VS2003 version of that article would make more sense.

Comment: @user3521733 The 2013 version of the documentation includes this: "You can use the extern keyword to keep the compiler from generating the same instantiation code in more than one object module." This sentence is notably absent from the 2012 version, so I don't know if extern has that effect there or not. In any case, it will be good to know when/if we move up to 2013.